# NHibernate ICriterion .NET delegate mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate in a repository pattern with DI to keep things flexible.  I don't want the associated interfaces to expose anything vendor specific like ICriterion.  But, I want my query class to accept a delegate that I can put into the .Where clause.

I need something like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> Execute(Func<MyClass, bool> selector)
{
    return session
        .QueryOver<MyClass>()
        .Where(selector)
        .....
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this or am I going about it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going the wrong way. I think your code works ; your problem being that you retrieve all your table in memory where filtering is done.

I guess this should enable filtering at DB level for criteria which can be translated to SQL :

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> Execute(Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> selector)
{
    return session.Query<MyClass>().Where(selector).ToList();
}
```

and I bet this should work too :

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> Execute(Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> selector)
{
    return session.QueryOver<MyClass>().Where(selector).ToList();
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Yep, that did it thanks. I got confused because the Expression class exists in 2 namespaces: NHibernate and System.Linq. This one uses the Linq Expression.